# I have json values , how to save into mongodb using spring mvc

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

I have class like "location".
"Location" class have four field.
fields are:id,city,state,country..
country is seprate class it contains 2 field , country code, country name , 2 fields must read from location class..
if i write "locationMongoRepository.save()", then it shows error as bound mismatch. please give solution for how to save in mongodb.

```
 public void insertLocation() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, JSONException{



        FileInputStream inp;
        Workbook workbook;
        try {

        inp = new FileInputStream( "/home/Downloads/eclipse/Workspace/Samplboot-master latest/cityListForIndia1.xlsx" );
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create( inp );
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        boolean isFirstRow = true;
        ArrayList<String> rowName = new ArrayList<String>();
        for ( Iterator<Row> rowsIT = sheet.rowIterator(); rowsIT.hasNext(); )
        {
            Row row = rowsIT.next();
            JSONObject jRow = new JSONObject();


            if(isFirstRow)
            {
                for ( Iterator<Cell> cellsIT = row.cellIterator(); cellsIT.hasNext(); )
                {
                    Cell cell = cellsIT.next();

                    rowName.add(cell.getStringCellValue());


                }
            isFirstRow = false;
            }   
            else
            {
                JSONObject jRowCountry= new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jRowLocation= new JSONObject();

                jRowLocation.put("city", row.getCell(0));
                jRowLocation.put("state", row.getCell(1));
                jRowCountry.put("country",row.getCell(2) );
                jRowCountry.put("countryCode", row.getCell(3) );
                jRowLocation.put("country", jRowCountry);
                System.out.println("Location"+jRowLocation.toString()); 

            }


        }




    }
        catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Invalid Format, Only Excel files are supported");
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Check if the input file exists and the path is correct");
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Unable to generate Json");
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Spring Data to support working with MongoDB and it's really helpful. You should read this article to get its idea and applied to your case https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-mongodb-hello.

P/S: In case you can't use Spring Data to work with MongoDB, please provide more detail in your code/ your exception so we can investigate it more detail.